What is the relationship between the applied reverse bias in a p-n junction to the band gap of the semiconductor?

Consider a p-n junction under reverse bias. The difference in the Fermi Energy of the p-side and the n-side is $qV_r$ where $q$ is the elementary charge, and $V_r$ is the applied reverse voltage. What happens when $qV_r$ is larger than the band gap of my semiconductor? Is this case nothing special?
Now what if I have carriers combining radiatively, causing a reverse current flow and subsequent power generation. Each recombination results in a chemical potential $\Delta \mu=qV_r$. If $\Delta \mu>E_g$, does a single carrier recombining radiatively result in work greater than the bandgap of the semiconductor? Thanks!

Depends on a lot of things. Consider Zener diodes…
